# Zoom in on mouse position in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

**Question:**

How do I zoom in on the mouse position on mouse wheel scrolls?

**Details:**

I am trying to merge [this complete solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12758891/654789) on Stack Overflow, which allows for zooming of the stage, with [this incomplete solution](http://pastebin.com/hHJvA4jS), which allows for zooming in around the mouse when clicked. I have forked the jsfiddle code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pukster/LKvv3/1/). The code works fine once you get it zoomed in, but upon first scrolling, the stage jumps to a different location and I can't figure out why. Can anyone tell me why it is happening, and how to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but you are using the mouse position relative to the page not the canvas

Answer (score 0):

When you zoom, the position under your mouse position gets changed (the reason of jumping). To move back the position to its original position, you need to pan the offset( difference between the previous position and the new position(after zoom)). To avoid stage jumping to a different location, you can use `stage.setOffset` function of KineticJS.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rpaul/ckwu7u86/3/