# Which canvas library makes zooming, panning, drag & drop possible?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, frameworks, drag-and-drop

Basically, my application needs to do at least the following things:

- drag & drop
- zooming & panning
- image rotation
- ability to manipulate canvas objects with code
- svg import (if possible, not important though)

My requirements are quite basic but is it me or do these canvas libraries seem so limited in functionality? I know the canvas spec isn't final, but I've seen some stunning canvas projects out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had good experiences with kinetic js (http://kineticjs.com/).

it seems to cover all your requirements.

see also: [Zoom and Pan in KineticJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633554/zoom-and-pan-in-kineticjs)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it. Though, my minimal experience with kinetic.js taught me that dragging elements on a big canvas isn't quite smooth.

Comment: Seems to do what I was hoping for, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Konva](http://konvajs.github.io/docs/) will be suitable for you. It is based on [KineticJs](http://kineticjs.com/) which is no longer maintained by its author. But Konva is maintained and it has very nice documentation. It seems to cover all your requirements.